# Could there have been primeval energy associated with the primeval particle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, particle-physics, big-bang, theory-of-everything

I was researching up on the big bang theory and came across the primeval atom hypothesis. I know that nothing is known of this time period but I was wondering hypothetically is it is possible. I am a layman so I am not 100% sure if I understand the concept completely, especially with all the conflicting information when it comes to topics involving the theory of everything.

Thank you for the help and patience!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

There is no modern primeval atom hypothesis. The *primeval atom hypothesis* is just the name used for the earliest proposal of what is now known as the *big bang theory*, proposed by George Lemaître in 1927. It is not a reference to a particle in the quantum mechanical sense.

What Lemaître called "the primeval atom" is the emergence, in general relativity, of a point of infinite density and infinite temperature in the finite past. This is now referred to as "the primordial singularity".

The prediction of such a point, even by such an extremely successful theory as general relativity, does not necessarily mean that such a point exists. Infinities are usually nonsense results. If they show up in your model for something that doesn't seem to exist, they're confirmation that that thing doesn't exist. If they show up in your model for something that does seem to exist, they're evidence that there's something wrong with the model. The universe seems to exist, so it's possible that the calculated infinity just marks the point at which general relativity stops being a good description for how the universe behaves.

The period between the likely beginning of the universe until the moment that our best mathematical representations of how the universe behaves no longer generate results that might be nonsense is known as the Planck Epoch.

The total energy of the universe is unknown. There's a popular hypothesis that it might be zero (potential energy is negative, so summing potential energy and energy can get you a zero result).